# W8 Registry issue? Calling shell script from within C++ app but no arguments get passed

Tags: c++, bash, shell, arguments, registry

I have a C++ program that uses a `system()` call to execute and send arguments to a shell script. It worked fine on my Windows 8.1 computer. Now I'm trying to run the same thing on a new Windows 8.1 laptop. The shell script gets executed but NO arguments are received.

The C++ code

```
system(("C:/script.sh file.png &").c_str());
```

in the shell script I verify the number of arguments received.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "received arguments:  $# "
```

I can execute and pass arguments to the script manually from Git Bash

```
$ sh script.sh file.png 
received arguments: 1
```

But if I do it with the `system()` call within c++, the received arguments is always 0. The same exact code works well on the other machine. The problem seems to be related to the Windows Registry. The first time I ran the C++ program on the new laptop, Windows asked me what program it should use to execute the shell script. I selected PowerShell. Yet this only caused PowerShell to open/close in a frenzy and I had to restart the computer. Then I went to explorer and associated the .sh to be opened with Git Bash. Now executing the script from within the C++ program works, safe for the passing of arguments.

Is it possible that my Registry setting somehow prohibit the passing of data?

[image: Windows Registry for .sh scripts]

Comment: `system()` may not be the right tool. Have a look into [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) instead. It does away with much of the guesswork.

Comment: thx @IInspectable - for now `system()` actually works so I'll stick with it. But will definitely consider your suggestion for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calling `system("/path/to/bash C:/script.sh file.png &")` to make the life easier for the OS, which otherwise needs to launch the program suggested in the shebang.

Comment: Now the system has to guess the location. Also, forward slashes will make your life anything but easier. The path separator on Window is a backslash.

Comment: It will compile, as long as you escape the backslash, e.g.: `C:\\script.sh`.

Comment: @IInspectable: Strange, I have to use 4 backslashes, in order to have a successful compile and run in Cygwin: `int i = system("bash C:\\\\script.sh file.png");`. Anyways, the OP's question is about passing the script to the right program and I do believe it is a good workaround at least.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Just `system("bash C:/script.sh file.png &")` made it work!